# Javascript variable name to <select name="">

Tags: javascript, variables, addition

i got this function and a button to add a field(dropdown field) now my question is how can i pass my var x = 1 to 
select name ="f_keuringsrapport_id1" so i generate a diffrent name everytime i add a dropdown field

```
<div class="container1">   
<button class="add_form_field">Add New Field &nbsp; </button> </div>
```

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10;
        var wrapper         = $(".container1");
        var add_button      = $(".add_form_field") var x = 1;
        $(add_button).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if(x < max_fields){
                    x++;
                    $(wrapper).append('<div><select name ="f_variable_id1" [var.options;htmlconv=no]"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
                }
                else
                    {
                    alert('You Reached the limits')
                }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
});`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `es6` [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to achieve this. Something like below

```
 $(wrapper).append(`<div><select name ="f_keuringsrapport_id${x}" [var.materiaaloptions;htmlconv=no]"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>`); //add input box
```

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for that. I forgot to add it :)

Comment: No worries mate :)

Comment: I tried it but i still dont get number back this is the result if i inspect it name="f_variable_id${x}"

Comment: @KevinF , make sure to use  ` ` instead of `" "`  when you are appending the `div` element

Comment: Thanks guys it works !

Comment: please accept the answer if it resolved your query